# Moving of two buttons

Tags: uibutton, swift3

I have 2 buttons and then I hide one of this I want to move another button to position of this button.

I want ask about variant with constraints and without it.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a button like the code below.

```
func setupButton() {
    button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
    //      SIZE
    button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width / 2, height: 50)
    //      POSITION
    button.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: 200)
    //      BACKGOUND COLOUR
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    //      CORNER RADIUS
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    //      TEXT COLOUR
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: UIControlState.normal)
    //      SET TEXT
    button.setTitle("press me", for: UIControlState.normal)
    //      SET FONT SIZE
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    //      BUTTON FUNCTION
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    //      ADD BUTTON TO VIEW
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Then you can hide it in the buttonPressed function and setup your new button in buttonPressed too.